# O que significa uma variável de dupla precisão?

Tags: variáveis, terminologia, tipagem

Gostaria de entender o significado de uma variável de dupla precisão.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normalmente chamada de `double`, é a variável que armazena um número de [**ponto flutuante**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) com espaço para indicar números maiores, seja na parte inteira, seja na parte decimal. Ele é o "irmão" do tipo `float` que é o tipo de simples precisão. Geralmente o `float` ocupa 4 bytes e o `double` ocupa 8 bytes. Algumas implementações ocupam 10 bytes e até 16 bytes, embora nesse caso costume ser chamado de quadrupla precisão.

Na verdade [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é apenas um nome para um local de armazenamento. Valores possuem tipos. Em linguagens de tipagem estática as variáveis aceitam valores de apenas um tipo conforme declaração em código.

Tipos de ponto flutuante costumam ser implementados por representação binária para que os cálculos sejam feitos rapidamente pelos processadores. Se a representação fosse decimal o cálculo não seria natural para o processador e levaria bem mais tempo. Há uma desvantagem nessa escolha. Não há exatidão, então nem todos os números podem ser representados dessa forma. Sempre dá para representar um número muito próximo, que é quase o mesmo, mas não exatamente o mesmo. Não é um problema para cálculos científicos, mas para representar dinheiro ele não serve. Dinheiro precisa do valor exato. Nunca use `float` e `double` para dinheiro ou outros valores que precisam exatidão.

Então entenda que exatidão e precisão são coisas diferentes. Precisão tem mais a ver com a capacidade de expressar números mais extensos, mais casas à direita ou esquerda. **Precisão** é o grau de variação de resultados de uma medição. **Exatidão**, que se refere à conformidade com o valor real.

Números com ponto flutuante são armazenados com um [valor significante](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) multiplicado por uma [base fixa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(exponentiation)) elevada a um [expoente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation), além do sinal.

Precisão simples:

[image: Ponto flutuante precisão simples]

Precisão dupla:

[image: Ponto flutuante precisão dupla]

Quanto mais bits disponíveis mais o número pode ser preciso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).